# How to dynamically prevent / allow swipe gesture navigation in a WKWebView on Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I've noticed that the [cordova-plugin-wkwebkit-engine](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) plugin has a preference for `AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures`. However, there are some states of the application where I want to prevent swipe navigation and some state where I want to allow it.

I've noticed that there's an [`updateWithInfo`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/blob/5a97cc4cb32cb0d858e248cf9759f075e8132a0d/src/ios/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m#L281) function that will call [`updateSettings`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/blob/5a97cc4cb32cb0d858e248cf9759f075e8132a0d/src/ios/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m#L310), so I think the facilities to do this are all in place, but I'm not sure how to invoke that function from JavaScript land with the settings I want.

Is it possible to dynamically change these settings? If not, is there any code I could add to this plugin that would enable me to change these settings from JavaScript dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are only set on app launch, so you can't reuse the updateWithInfo and updateSettings functions.

You'll need to create a new plugin that allows you to set the `wkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` with the value you want (YES or NO)

Read the [plugin development guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) if you don't know how to create a plugin.

From the plugin you can get the WKWebView downcasting the webview (it's an UIView) like this:

`WKWebView * myWKWebView = (WKWebView *)self.webView;`

Then you can set `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` to YES

`myWKWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;`

Comment: Thanks! This totally helped me get started -- then I just ended up copying code form the `cordova-keyboard-plugin`.